# Changing YouTube associated website wait time

Tags: youtube

I stupidly changed the associated website on my YouTube page on Thursday and now (Monday) it still gives me the warning:

> You have recently changed your associated website. Please wait for some time before changing it again.

I've waited over four days now, and it has reset to let me change my associated website. I'm verified, have over 500 subscribers. We have had this channel for over a year, and all other requirements are met. Not to mention, it was associated with our website four days ago. I've cleared my cache, history and everything on my browser, and it still fails to add back the associated website I had there.

What is the wait time before I can get my associated website back into action?